# How much room do I need to play Ring Fit Adventure?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I'm interested in Ring Fit Adventure, but given the layout of my room, I have a relatively narrow strip of space between the Dresser/TV and the end of my bed. Is this enough room to successfully perform all or most of the exercises or will I find myself cramped and struggling to follow along?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to perform every exercise, you should have enough space to:

- Stretch vertically while holding a Ring-Con. ([Overhead Arm Twist](https://youtu.be/OpLw94AQCy4?t=1244))

  - Most stretches don't extend the Ring-Con upwards, so there's some leniency here.
- Extend your arms left and right while holding a Ring-Con. ([Warrior II Pose](https://youtu.be/EGsBBDFi28I?t=1336))
- Lie on the ground with your feet extended. ([Plank](https://youtu.be/nOu5UWP0mbQ?t=2890))
- Sit with your legs extended diagonally in front of you. ([Fan Pose](https://youtu.be/EGsBBDFi28I?t=1897))
- Bend with hands extended forward and leg extended backwards. ([Warrior III Pose](https://youtu.be/Yg4LdPhT9aA?t=1930))

You can try most of these exercises yourself before buying the game to see if you have enough room.

[image: Overhead Arm Twist] [image: Warrior II Pose] [image: Plank] [image: Fan Pose] [image: Warrior III Pose]